# removing the existing products content on ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In this code i have $product_list which is obtained by executing the query given below, but using ajax when i click on the button link1 it must empty the $product_list.

So, how do i empty the content on `products_list` using ajax call when i click on `Link1` button?

In some of the questions I have seen using div id removing the content. bUT HERE I m not quite sure about it as i have a class and that to be removed.

Please help..

```
<?php
session_start(); //start session
include("config.inc.php"); //include config file
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Stores</title>
<link href="style/style1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="w3-bar w3-black">
  <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 1</a>
</div>

<div align="center">
<h3>Products</h3>
</div>
<?php
//List products from database
$results = $mysqli_conn->query("SELECT product_name, product_desc, product_code, product_image, product_price FROM products_list");
//Display fetched records as you please

$products_list =  '<ul class="products-wrp">';

while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
$products_list .= <<<EOT
<li>
<form class="form-item">
<h4>{$row["product_name"]}</h4>
<div>
<img src="images/{$row["product_image"]}" height="62" width="62">
</div>
<div>Price : {$currency} {$row["product_price"]}<div>

<div class="item-box">
    <input name="product_code" type="hidden" value="{$row["product_code"]}">
    <button type="submit">open</button>
</div>
</form>
</li>
EOT;

}
$products_list .= '</ul></div>';
echo $products_list;
?>
<script>
$(document).on("click", ".w3-button", function() {
  $("#products_list").empty()
});</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use it like `$('.products-wrp').html('')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the appropriate ID that you are using as jQuery selector to the element

Change

```
$products_list =  '<ul class="products-wrp">';
```

To

```
$products_list =  '<ul id ="products_list" class="products-wrp">';
```

It is important to recognize that none of the php variables exist in the browser, only in the server side code

Comment: i changed as u mentioned, could u pls tell me how to make a ajax call to empty this id when I click on Link1 button!

Comment: You really need to be a lot more specific about what you are trying to accomplish